# Differential equation plotting (Solved)

Tags: differential-equations

I am quite new to Mathematica so sorry if this is quite a simple fix. I was just wondering if anyone knew a solution that could help me fix this. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: how is `plot` defined

Comment: Ah yeah, it's a Capital thanks I fixed that up, but I still have an error from the DSolve.

Comment: `ca` is black (not blue) in your screenshot. It indicates that it has a definition, which should not be the case.  Also, you have a `;` after the definition of `odes`. Remove it so you can see what it actually evaluates to.  The same with the DSolve line. That'll make it clear to you what is happening.

Comment: Thanks for the help I did as you said but I am still unsure how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you are looking for.

```
odes = {ca'[t] == -k1*ca[t], cr'[t] == k1*ca[t] - k2*cr[t], 
  cs'[t] == k2*cr[t] - k3, ct'[t] == k3, ca[0] == ca0, cr[0] == 0, 
  cs[0] == 0, ct[0] == 0}

sol = DSolve[odes, {ca[t], cr[t], cs[t], ct[t]}, t][[1]] // Simplify

With[{expr = {ca[t], cr[t], cs[t], ct[t]} /. sol}, 
 Manipulate[Plot[expr, {t, 0, 10}], {{ca0, 0.2}, .1, 1}, {{k1, 0.2}, .1, 
   1}, {{k2, 2}, .1, 3}, {{k3, 0.2}, .1, 1}]]
```

or

```
With[{expr = {ca[t], cr[t], cs[t], ct[t]} /. sol}, 
 Manipulate[Plot[expr, {t, 0, 10}], {ca0, .1, 1}, {k1, 0, 1}, {k2, 2, 3}, {k3, 0, 1}]]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, your code was spot on. I appreciate the help.